# I want to Edit the text in Cell of a JQgrid, without editing the existing Text present while editing

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I want to Edit EX cell only but dont want to edit EX text in it... [image]

Example EX in that cell should be fixed and want to add EX/E2 or EX/E5 like this in that cell...
can anyone tell me the code to write in this event or editoptions
 in ***val*** i am getting **EX**

```
afterEditCell: function (id, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
     $("#" + iRow + "_" + name).bind('blur', function (e) {
         $('#grid').saveCell(iRow, iCol);
     });
}


editoptions: {
                    dataEvents: [
                        {
                          type: 'keypress',
                          fn: function (event, rowid) {
                              if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39)) && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength) || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) && (event.which == 8))))
                              {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
                                if ((e.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (e.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                }
```

Comment: basically i want to edit some text in "EX" cell i.e. i can add text ahead of EX but cannot delete or Edit EX....
example:-  EX/E4,  EXafdasfa, etc..
Need Help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you use [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/) you can use a custom element definition and with a help of custom_element and custom_value to do what you want. ore on the you can [read here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edittype) (see custom element type).

Bellow is the code for your wed field

```
colModel :[
...
   { name:'wed1',
    edittype: 'custom',
    editoptions : {
        custom_element : function (value, options) {
            var val = value.split("/"), rval;
            var el = "<label for='note'>"+val[0]+"/</label>";
                if(val[1] !== undefined) {
                    val.shift(); 
                    rval = val.join(",");
                } else {
                    rval = '';
                }
            el += "<input type='text' value='"+rval+"'/>";
            return $(el);
        },
        custom_value : function (elem, operation, value) {
            if(operation === 'get') {
                return $(elem[0]).text() + $(elem[1]).val();
            } else if(operation === 'set') {
                $('input',elem).val(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just idea how to do it. In the real example you will need to analyze if the input string contain , or /, but in any case you can use another approach to separate the original value of the cell

Comment: any other option than "custom element"
tell me in the existing Problem itself

Comment: Never try, but maybe you can use the [pattern property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) of the html element